# Ruby on Rails undefined method `products_path' routing issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, routes, undefined, nested-routes

It's been awhile since I've worked in Rails and I'm having some issues with setting up my routes properly. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
URL: http://localhost:3000/admin/products/new

Error: undefined method `products_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f9f569d0150>:0x007f9f578ccb18>
```

rake routes

```
admin_products     GET    /admin/products(.:format)          admin/products#index
                   POST   /admin/products(.:format)          admin/products#create
new_admin_product  GET    /admin/products/new(.:format)      admin/products#new
edit_admin_product GET    /admin/products/:id/edit(.:format) admin/products#edit
admin_product GET         /admin/products/:id(.:format)      admin/products#show
                   PUT    /admin/products/:id(.:format)      admin/products#update
                   DELETE /admin/products/:id(.:format)      admin/products#destroy
```

routes.rb

```
Aneprize::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :admins, :users

  namespace :admin do
    match '/', to: 'dashboard#index', as: '/'

    authenticated :admin do
      root to: 'dashboard#index', as: :root

      resources :products do
        resource  :contest
        resources :bids
        resources :photos
        resources :tags
      end
    end
  end

  root to: 'contests#index'
end
```

product.rb

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :retail_price, :short_description, :long_description, :weight

  has_one  :contest, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :photos,  dependent: :destroy
  has_many :bids,    dependent: :destroy
  has_many :tags

  validates :name, :short_description, :long_description, presence: true
  validates :retail_price, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 0 }
  validates :weight, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than_or_equal_to: 1 }
end
```

contest.rb

```
class Contest < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id, :duration

  belongs_to :product, dependent: :destroy

  validates :product_id, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validates :duration,   presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 2 }
end
```

product.rb

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id, :image_url

  belongs_to :product

  validates :product_id, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
  validates :image_url,  presence: true, format: { with: /^[^-\d].+/ }
end
```

bid.rb

```
class Bid < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :product_id, :account_id, :amount

  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :product, dependent: :destroy

  validates :account_id, :product_id, :amount, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
end
```

tag.rb

```
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :product_id

  belongs_to :product

  validates :name, presence: true, format: { with: /^\D+$/ }
  validates :product_id, presence: true, numericality: { only_integer: true, greater_than: 0 }
end
```

Comment: Run `rake routes` to see all routes. Actually, the route should be like `admin_products_path` as you have `:admin` namespace

Comment: Sergey, running rake routes gives me the following: 

new_admin_product GET /admin/products/new(.:format) admin/products#new

Comment: You have `admin_products` if you see. That's what you need. Try iy out with `<%= link_to "Admin products", admin_products_path %>`

Comment: Oh, I got what's wrong. I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you are getting error at `URL: http://localhost:3000/admin/products/new` so you should have some problems with your form builder.

While you have products resources in `:admin` namespace you should take this fact into account while building form. Correct example is:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @product] do |f| %>
  ... # whatever
<% end %>
```

instead of just

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  ... # whatever
<% end %>
```

Comment: Wow. Now that I did not even know. I can't thank you enough! I've upvoted the answer as well to give credit where it's due. Thanks again!!!!

Comment: you might also need `, url: admin_product_path(resource)`

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in your new template you are calling `products_path`. Since it is under admin you should change it to `admin_products_path`

Comment: Hey Josh, I've got this in admin/dashboard/index.html.haml:
= link_to "Add Product", new_admin_product_path(@product)